# How do I set up a route to a url that ends with and number/id in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I route to a page that ends with an id?

```
E.G. 
before: site.com/messages/8
after:  site.com/messages/terrytibbs
```

I've tried:

```
match "/messages/:username" => "messages#id"
```

No luck so far. Just trying to make the url have a little more meaning by replacing the number with the username of the user the current user is talking to.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something simple without having to change your routes etc, why not do this:

```
class Message

  def to_param
    "#{id}-{username}"
  end

...
end
```

Assuming you have a username attribute on your message. That will make your url look like:

site.com/messages/8-terrytibbs

this works because of the following (say in irb):

> > > "8-terrytibbs".to_i
> > >       => 8

and when rails looks up your message in your controller it will do the same thing to the id parameter.

EDIT: there is an excellent railscast on this here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url and an updated version here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised

Comment: I've watched the revised rails cast a good few times now and I still quite don't get how it works. My username column for my users is in a User table not the Message table.

Comment: ah, that makes a difference. So you want to see all the messages for a particular user?

Comment: Yep so let's say I have a user "Maureen" and a user "Genesis". If Maureen wants to view the message thread between her and Genesis site.com/messages/8 will take her there. Number 8 is the parent_id for all messages between the two of them. I prefer to use the username of each user stored in the users table. So for Maureen to see genesis messages she'll type site.com/messages/genesis and for genesis to see the messages between her and Maureen she'll type site.com/messages/maureen. So I'd like a user to view all messages of a particular conversation using the recipients username instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. I think it's what you need.

> FriendlyId is the "Swiss Army bulldozer" of slugging and permalink plugins for Ruby on Rails. It allows you to create pretty URLs and work with human-friendly strings as if they were numeric ids for Active Record models.
>
> Using FriendlyId, it's easy to make your application use URLs like:
>
> ```
>      http://example.com/states/washington
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
>      http://example.com/states/4323454
> ```

Comment: Sure it's possible. But why not use a gem instead?

Comment: I thought it would be as easy as typing out a new route but just in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is set up correctly you have to change the Controller to use the correct parameters.

Assuming your MessagesController does:

```
def id
  User.find(params[:id])
end
```

change to:

```
def id
  User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

I would also recommend adding indexing on user name.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you just need to make sure the route is pointing at a proper action on the controller, like so:

Say the action you want this to point to is named `show`, here is how you would define the route:

```
match 'messages/:username' => 'messages#show'
```

Then if you navigate to `messages/8`, `params[:username]` will be set to `'8'` (parameters always come in as `String`'s.

Likewise if you navigate to `messages/terrytibbs`, `params[:username]` will be set to `'terrytibbs'`.

Try reading [Chapter 3-3.5 of the Rails Routing Guide, it provides a good overview of how to bind parameters to a route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) like you are attempting to do.

Comment: I achieved a similar thing with site.com/username earlier in this project many months ago. In that situation I was only match :username to the users controller and show action so that was easy. In this instance ID isn't an action. I'll read over the docs again. Thanks